# What are the implications of an Australian-domiciled S&P 500 ETF?

Tags: etf, australia, international

So I'm considering investing in the [Australian IVV S&P 500 ETF](https://www.blackrock.com/au/individual/products/275304/ishares-s-p-500-etf-fund). In 2018 it was converted from a US-domiciled fund listed on the ASX using depository receipts to an Australian-domiciled fund. I have a couple of questions about what that means for an Aussie investor.

1. So one of the main advantages is that we don't have to fill in [W-8BEN](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf) forms. But is this always a financial advantage? Could there be a situation where I'd end up better off if I had bought an equivalent US-domiciled S&P 500 depository receipts fund and then filled in the W-8BEN form etc?
2. How does an Australian-domiciled foreign fund compare to an Australian dollar hedged fund like [IHVV](https://www.blackrock.com/au/individual/products/271027/ishares-s-and-p-500-aud-hedged-etf)? Does it being Australian-domiciled mean that it is in any way hedged compared to a US-domiciled fund? Or is hedging really entirely tangential to where a fund is domiciled?

Is there anything else I should be aware of that should make me consider whether (all else being equal) a US-domiciled/depository receipts fund would be the better choice?